# What is the intended use for an extra deep skillet?

Tags: cast-iron, skillet, sauce-pan

I had to resist purchasing a so-called "deep" cast iron skillet that was on sale for a good price because I couldn't imagine what I could do with it that I couldn't already to with my regular cast iron skillet or my stainless steel saucepans...

This particular skillet is just over three inches deep.

I've been slowly crossing over from teflon to cast iron, so I like to grab good north american-made stuff if I see it on sale, but I just couldn't justify this one because it seemed a bit niche.

Comment: ...fried chicken comes to mind.

Comment: I typically think of them as ‘chicken fryers’, but they’re a convenient shape for arroz con pollo if you have a lid for it, as they’re easier to stir to the bottom of than a taller Dutch oven.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As moscafj mentions in a comment, I would mainly think of a deep skillet as being useful for deep frying. Depending on shape, it might also be usable as a Dutch oven (at least for some Dutch oven uses, like baking buns) if you can find an appropriate lid.

It is not something I would purchase for a “general purpose” kitchen.

Comment: I agree, it's one of those niche things. Also very heavy for regular use.

Comment: Ok, I can see it as a deep fryer.  I don't really do much of that as is, and I'm planning on getting a dutch oven in the future for chicken, bread... so I'll probably give the deep skillet a miss.